# Excel VBA Run-Time Error 91

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping someone might see the problem with the coding below, which consistently generates a Run-time error 91, object variable or with variable not set.

I have the following:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, UseRow As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Basic Data History")
LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Basic_Data_Table").Range.Rows.Count
UseRow = LastRow
Set test = sht.ListObjects("Basic_Data_Table").DataBodyRange.Cells(2, 1)
```

The LastRow assignment works perfectly.  I have no problems with it.

The error occurs on the Set test line.  I have tried this using DataBodyRange(2,1) as well, without using "Cells."  I don't think it's an out-of-range issue either (I've played with the parameters).

I added this "set test" line to help debug an "if" statement below that was generating the same error.  I was hoping my problem was that maybe I wasn't setting the object properly (I was using the sht.listobjects ... in the if statement).  I also tried taking out the "set" to see if that would work.  No luck.

I've looked at a lot of different help write-ups on this site and on others.  I actually modified this from something on TheSpreadsheetGuru.

I've now reached the point where I'm "insistent" that there's nothing wrong with what I wrote, and steam is coming out my ears ... yes, I know that's wrong and never helpful.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong???  Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you add this line just before the problem line, what is the output ?  `Debug.Print sht.ListObjects("Basic_Data_Table").DataBodyRange Is Nothing`

Comment: Tim - It shows "True."

Comment: `test` is a Range object? Are there at least 2 rows of data in the Table?

Comment: No, I don't have test defined as a range object.  And, while I had set up a table with a header row, and an empty row underneath, I did not put any data in it, and I am beginning to realize that is the core of my problem.  I have been working on this for hours, as well as the approx. 45 minutes since I submitted my question.  I was trying to deal with the "empty spreadsheet" situation as a special case, but I think you are saying (and Tim's question led me there as well) that this won't work - that I have to have at least a line of data in the table below the header for this to work - correct?

Comment: Cells(2,1) refers to the second row in the data range of your table (which does not include header row). If you only have 1 row, DataBodyRange.Cells(2, 1) is nothing. If your intention was to set "test" to the first row, just change Cells(2,1) to Cells(1,1). 
On a separte note, you should declare test as a range object. Faster, smaller, cleaner code and no confusion.

Comment: You might also test the number of rows in the table before setting your range:  
if sht.ListObjects("Basic_Data_Table").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count > 0 Then ...

Comment: That line I just posted can serve as a test before you go ahead with the rest of your process.

Comment: Thank you.  For some reasons, Cells (1,1) also seems to generate an error.  I also tried doing an Msgbox sht.ListObjects("Basic_Data_Table").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, and that throws Error 91.  It seems that I actually need to have something in that row under the header, or I have a problem. I have made sure, incidentally, that the row under the header is included in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a **new** table contains no data, its DataBodyRange is Nothing. When you add any data to the table, DataBodyRange is set to a range, and even if you delete the data later, it will remain initialized.

In your situation, the simplest solution might be to just test DataBodyRange before doing anything, i.e.,

```
If Not sht.ListObjects("Basic_Data_Table").DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then 
   your code here
End if
```

or

```
If sht.ListObjects("Basic_Data_Table").DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Or use On Error GoTo and check for Error 91.